# Problem in searching with linq using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have this code working as well for searching with data I typed manually :

```
 Dim Collections = New String() {"Frensh", "Britich", "English"}
 Dim textToSearch As String = dr7.Text.ToLower()
 ListBox1.Visible = False
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(textToSearch) Then Return
 Dim result As String() = (From i In Collections Where i.Trim().Contains(textToSearch) Select i).ToArray()
 If result.Length = 0 Then Return
 ListBox1.Items.Clear()
 ListBox1.Items.AddRange(result)
 ListBox1.Visible = True
```

Now I want to load the data not using array but from database and I did this code :

```
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT distinct t2 FROM add_emp where  t2 like '%" & dr7.Text.Trim & "%'"
        Dim dtb As New DataTable
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
        con.Open()
        Dim dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, con)
        dtb.Clear()
        dad.Fill(dtb)
        dad.Dispose()
        con.Close()
          
        Dim textToSearch As String = dr7.Text.ToLower()
        ListBox1.Visible = False
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(textToSearch) Then Return

        Dim result As String() = (From i In dtb Where i.Trim().Contains(textToSearch) Select i).ToArray()

        If result.Length = 0 Then Return
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(result)
        ListBox1.Visible = True
```

What I tried to do , that I replaced "collection" as array to "dtb" as DataTable and the error appeared for this line , and I do not know handle this code to be working as well :

```
 Dim result As String() = (From i In dtb Where i.Trim().Contains(textToSearch) Select i).ToArray()
```

Comment: What's the LINQ query for when you have already filtered the result in the SQL? Also, the LINQ query is built to deal with strings in an array, now you're dealing with DataRows. + Why checking whether `String.IsNullOrEmpty(textToSearch)` after you have used that value in a SQL? (BTW, use Parameters, don't concatenate strings to build a query). Are you trying a case insensitive re-filter -- You can ditch the LINQ stuff and just check if the DataTable has Rows.

Comment: I'm new with LINQ I mention the problem in query , but i need to handle the code : "i.Trim().Contains(textToSearch)"

Comment: Your `i` in the second snippet is not a string anymore, it's a DataRow, so that line doesn't make sense. As mentioned, you have already filtered the data in the SQL, why do you think you also need LINQ there?

Comment: Because : first I did array and after I type in combobox(dr7.text) it filter the any of character (textToSearch) .Second snippet I load the data from db and need to do a filter Like what I did from Snippet one .

Comment: No, you don't. You need to set the DataTable as the `DataSource` of your ListBox and its `DisplayMember` to `"t2"`. The results have already been filtered in the SQL.

Comment: I tried as you said you are right and It's working , I tired for 5 hours to find a solution, you saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have separated the data access code from the user interface code.

`Using...End Using` blocks ensure that you database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. Don't declare your connection outside the method where it is used. You created your `DataTable` 3 lines above. Why would you need to `Clear` it? The `DataAdapter` will open and close the connection if it finds it closed. Otherwise, it will leave it open.

As to the linq code. You want to loop through data rows. `DataTable` does not implement `IEnumerable` but it provides an extension method to return an enumerable (`AsEnumerable`). The first column of the DataTable is a Field(Of String) with index 0.

```
Private dr7 As New TextBox
Private Function GetValuesForListBox(SearchString As String) As String()
    Dim strSql = "SELECT distinct t2 FROM add_emp where  t2 like @dr7;"
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, con)
        dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dr7", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = $"%{SearchString}%"
        dad.Fill(dtb)
    End Using 'Closes and disposes Connection and disposes DataAdapter

    Dim result = (From row As DataRow In dtb.AsEnumerable
                  Select row.Field(Of String)(0)).ToArray
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub FillListBox()
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr7.Text) Then Return
    Dim Result = GetValuesForListBox(dr7.Text.Trim)
    If Result.Length = 0 Then Return
    ListBox1.Visible = False
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Result)
    ListBox1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As you're calling `AsEnumerable`, you're already using LINQ to DataSet - `AsEnumerable` is an extension method, not a member of `DataTable` - so you may as well go all in and use the `Field` extension on `DataRow` too: `Select row.Field(Of String)("t2")`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I forget about the .Field(Of T). Thanks!